# Should libraries not available using NuGet also be placed in the packages folder?

Tags: .net, nuget

Our build server does a package restore before builds so that we don't have heavy source control check outs and commits. We have some home grown libraries that we include in some of our projects and I was wondering if using the packages folder that NuGet creates is a good place for them.

The long term solution would probably be to create our own local NuGet repository and serve the libraries from there. But until then...

Comment: As the packages folder is usually excluded from source control, you should not drop anything there on your own, but the NuGet packages which can be restored.

Answer (score 1):

`packages` folder usually is considered to be safe to delete. I'd say you can put them their but you shouldn't. It's much better to place them into separate folder like `libs`.